# Error: No Contract deployed with name Ebay

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity, ethers.js

Getting this error while testing my Ebay Contract
ITs An Ebay Smart Contract Where Products are being Auctioned

```
yarn run v1.22.15
warning package.json: No license field
$ "E:\Block Chain Projects\30_SMARTCONTRACTS.sol\A Way To Testing\node_modules\.bin\hardhat" test


  Ebay Smart Contract
    Upload Product function
This is deployer0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266
      1) "before each" hook for "if the base Price is less than 0 or invalid should revert"


  0 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) Ebay Smart Contract
       "before each" hook for "if the base Price is less than 0 or invalid should revert":
     Error: No Contract deployed with name Ebay
      at Object.getContract (node_modules\@nomiclabs\hardhat-ethers\src\internal\helpers.ts:447:11)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\Test.js:18:12)



error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

MY TEST.js

```
//it
//describe
//beforeEach

const { expect, assert } = require("chai");
const { ethers, getNamedAccounts } = require("hardhat");
describe("Ebay Smart Contract", async function() {
  let Ebay;
  let deployer;
  const product = {
    name: "CYCLE",
    description: "gare cycles",
    BasePrice: "5",
  };
  beforeEach(async () => {
    deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer;
    console.log("This is deployer" + deployer);
    Ebay = await ethers.getContract("Ebay", deployer);
  });

  describe("Upload Product function", async function() {
    it("if the base Price is less than 0 or invalid should revert", async function() {
      expect(
        Ebay.UploadProduct(product.name, product.description, product.BasePrice)
      ).to.be.revertedWith(Base_Price_cannot_be_Zero());
    });
  });
});
```

My deploy.js

```
const { ethers, deployments } = require("hardhat");
require("dotenv").config();
async function main() {
  // const { deploy, log } = deployments;
  //const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts();

  const Auction = await ethers.getContractFactory("Ebay");
  const auction = await Auction.deploy();
  await auction.deployed();
  console.log(auction.address);

  // const Auction = await deploy("Auctionbargain", {
  //   from: deployer,
  //   args: [],
  //   log: true,
  //   waitconfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1,
  // });
  //console.log(Auction.address);
  //log("------------------------------------");
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

hardhatconfig.js

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require("hardhat-deploy");
require("dotenv").config();

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: {
    compilers: [{ version: "0.6.6" }, { version: "0.8.8" }],
  },
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      chainId: 31337,
    },
    // goerli: {
    // url: GOERLI_RPC_URL,
    // accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
    // chainId: 5,
    // blockConfirmations: 6,
    // },
  },
  namedAccounts: {
    deployer: {
      default: 0, // here this will by default take the first account as deployer
    },
  },
};
```

It was correctly deployed but gave error everytime i try to test it
I Tried using ABI in place of deployer in my test.js but it did give me the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you deployed the contract on the same network on which you’re testing? it says:

Error: No Contract deployed with name Ebay

this can happen if you‘re testing on another network where the contract isn’t deployed at.

Also consider that the contract is really named Ebay. I can’t check that since you didn’t provide the solidity file.